# Does faster code uses less system resources?

Tags: optimization

Generally speaking, does the faster code uses less system resources?

If yes, should I suppose that reading a file from file system in `0.02` sec is lighter (better?) than querying the database that took `0.03` sec?

Please note:

- The speed is not a concern here, I'm just talking about the system resources like memory, etc.
- Also it's a general question, I'm not comparing file system vs. database. That's just an example.

I'm aware that I need to do different benchmarks or profiling in my code to find the precise answer, but as I said above, I'm curious to see if it's generally true or not.

I used to do speed benchmarks in my project to define the `better` solution, however I never thought that I might need to do benchmarks on memory usage for example. I did it a few times, but it wasn't serious. So, that's why I'm asking this question. I hope it make sense at all.

Comment: Speed and space are two opposite dimensions, generally. Complicated solutions (not complex) consume a lot of resources and are inefficient but it's another debate...

Comment: @Aubin I think I didn't get it, would you explain a little bit more or even better, post it as answer. thanks!

Comment: The way to use fewer resources is to do no more than necessary, and that will automatically be faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on *why* the code is faster.

One common way to optimise for speed, is to use a lot of some other resource.

With your example, both the database and the file system uses RAM memory to cache data. It's more likely that the database would actually be faster, because it uses a lot more RAM to cache data.

So, often faster code uses *more* resources.

Comment: Well, i never thought about that! I guess I have always tried to make resource-hungry applications somehow. Thanks for the answer, it's really good to understand such a thing! :)

Comment: Its a trade-off.. to save cpu processing you can cache pre-processed data into RAM or store it on file system or db!

Answer (score 0):

It very broad topic for discussion 
faster code mean what? If a code is all static compile time bind than naturally you get faster one.That is what structural programming like  C is base line.But,when you enter into object oriented programming just a static binding does not provides object oriented programming figure .So,you need class,objects which natually uses more system resources like  more cpu cycle and memory for  run time binding . If compared to C and java .yes C is definitely faster than java in some extend .If you run a single hello world example program from C and Java .You can see C takes less resource than java.It mean less CUP cycle and less memory.But in cost we may miss
reusability,maintainbaility,extendability.